# Performance issue with very high number of lists created in loop

Tags: c#, performance, list, garbage-collection

This is my first post here...
Please consider that I'm a hobby programmer.
**Symptom:**
My goal would be to improve performance of my code.
The program uses only 65% of CPU and 500Mb memory. There is another 800Mb free physical memory that is available for the program and about 30% of the CPU running idle. I don't know where can be the bottleneck for further utilizing resources and improving code performance.
**Background:**
I wrote a program that is mass testing a financial algorithm. This algorithm has a number of parameters and I'm trying to find the best combination of parameters. To do this I run it for all possible combination of parameters.
This algorithm has an input of data series. It iterates through the data series and produces a result.
So to do this I inserted the code of the algorithm into a Parallel.Foreach loop that runs once for each combination of parameters. The critical code for optimization is the loop.
Since the code is very long I post the backbone:

```
...
class candle : IComparable<candle>  //Data element to represent a candle and all chart data
    {
        public double open;
        public double high;
        ...40 more
    }
class param : IComparable<param>
{
    public int par1;
    public int par2;
    public int par3;
    ... a few more    
}
//Running program
{
List<candle> sourceCandleList = new List<candle>();
List<param> paramList = new List<param>(1000000);

// Code to populate sourceCandleList and paramList in here
}
// EDIT: Start parallel processing
Parallel.ForEach(paramList,
    p =>
    {
        List<candle> CandleList = new List<candle>(sourceCandleList.Count);
        foreach (var cndl in sourceCandleList)
           {
            candle c = new candle();
            c.open = cndl.open;
            c.high = cndl.high;
            ...
            //Run calculations and populate fields in CandleList
            }
         //Evaluate results
     }
```

The paramlist has about 140.000 elements. sourceCandleList has about 2.000 elements. This means that I continuously create lists with 2.000 items each and then drop the list after processing. I can see while running the code GC is cleaning about 200Mb memory per second. Currently 1 loop of the Parallel.ForEach takes 80ms. The program doesn't write any data to the disk and only very minimal to the console.
Perhaps one way to prevent GC working so much is to keep CandleList in the memory and then overwrite it when the next loop runs. For that I would need to define a static list for each thread but I'm not sure how is it possible. Maybe just create a bunch of lists and then try to catch a free one using TryEnter when a new thread starts?

---

**EDIT**
I didn't clearly state that the program first generates 2 lists: sourceCandleList and paramList. Then these are never changed anymore once they are complete. After these 2 lists are fully populated the program starts to test the algorithm: sourceCandleList is the input and one record from paramList is the set of parameters to apply. The problem is that the program defines a new CandleList each time. so I would need something like:

```
ConcurrentQueue<List<candle>> ListOfCanldes = new ConcurrentQueue<List<candle>>();
```

However I can't figure out the right syntax.

---

**Questions:**
Why is neither the CPU not memory fully utilized? Do I reach maximum read/write speed of memory!?
How could I avoid GC slowing the program?
How could I see how much time I'm actually loosing because of GC?
How could I improve performance?

Comment: Check an implementation of ObjectPool class

Comment: If you're trying to improve perf, the most important tool you can have is a profiler.  Use one.

Comment: Firstly - great first question! How are you seeing "the GC cleaning about 200 Mb memory per second"? Are you using a profiler, making your own calls to ask it, or what?

Comment: @arootbeer  I simply observed column "Working set delta (Memory)" in windows task manager.

Comment: So You make clone of sourceCandleList every time and the tested algorithm modifies that? You are looking for the best parameter and the quality of parameter is a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved with the following code. The reason is that I can't have multiple threads working on the same queue because I need to keep the order or elements. An additional order by is not needed in this case.
The result is that memory usage is 50% reduced and changes only very little while the program runs. Now the program runs all cores on 100%.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Parameters to test
        List<candle> paramList = new List<candle>();

        // Original list
        List<candle> sourceList = new List<candle>();

        // Create a copy for each thread
        int maxThreads = 16;
        ConcurrentBag<int> pool = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
        List<candle>[] processList = new List<candle>[maxThreads];
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxThreads - 1; i++)
        {
            pool.Add(i);
            processList[i] = sourceList.ConvertAll(p => p);
        }
        Parallel.For(0, paramList.Count,
        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxThreads },
        p =>
        {
            int slot = 0;
            int item;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                if (pool.TryTake(out item))
                {
                    slot = item;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
            lock (processList[slot])
            {
                // Do processing here
            }
            pool.Add(slot);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx , each thread can have its own List (using ThreadLocal<T> is one option), there is no need to shuffle through pool in this case.

Comment: Using `Parallel.For` Uses multiple threads. In this case the thread pool is controlled for you. In my example you can create as many threads you want. You are using a max. of 16 threads in your code snip. But not a guaranteed 16 threads. The `Parallel.For` does however resynchronize at the end of execution of that block. Which is convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Why is neither the CPU not memory fully utilized? Do I reach maximum read/write speed of memory!?

- Not enough information to tell. But using the `Parallel.ForEach` will limit the number of threads you are using.  Probably not be using a list, and instead something like `ConcurrentQueue` or `ConcurrentStack`.

I would do something like this to process them faster:

```
class Program
    {
        static ConcurrentQueue<candle> sourceCandleList = new ConcurrentQueue<candle>();
        static ConcurrentBag<param> paramList = new ConcurrentBag<param>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var threads = new List<Thread>();
            var numberOfThreads = 10;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
            {
                threads.Add(new Thread(Run));
            }
            threads.ForEach(i => i.Start());
        }
        static void Run()
        {
            candle item;
            while (sourceCandleList.TryDequeue(out item))
            {
                //do you processing here
            }
        }
    }
```

How could I avoid GC slowing the program? : **Stop worrying about the GC.**

How could I see how much time I'm actually loosing because of GC?
You could use VS 2015's profiling - or download a tool like Ant Profiler. But seriously stop worrying about the GC.

How could I improve performance? Refer to my code snip above. I dont know what else your program is doing though.

Comment: I updated the original question. I'm also no longer worried about GC. I may now be worried of writing a CPU intensive code that becomes a memory intensive code.